# Get-ChildItem returning wrong file types

Tags: powershell

I'm using the command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\*" "*.ps1" -Name -Recurse
```

To return a list of PowerShell scripts on my drive. However, it's returning .pdf, .docx, and .py (among others), as well as the .ps1 files. The list isn't the full list of files on the drive, so it has filtered some. The files that it returned that it shouldn't have, have no connection to PowerShell, even in the body of the document.

Does anyone know what's gong wrong?

Comment: `gci C:\ -filter *.ps1 -recurse -name`

Comment: That works, thanks. I'll read around further about the commands you've included to see if I can figure out what went wrong. Can you put this as an answer so that I can close the question, please?

Comment: @Joshcollins Don't forget to use `Get-Help` for extended information and examples, `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only error was the wildcard symbol after `C:\` - when you want to run the command and include the subfolders, you just have to add the `-recurse` switch, this switch will handle everything for you.

```
gci C:\ *.ps1 -recurse -name
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. gci is just an alias. Thanks @SimonS :)

Comment: @Joshcollins yes. i got tired of writing `get-childitem` ;-). you're welcome. run `get-alias -definition get-childitem` to see all its aliases